# Envelope Distort with JavaScript and HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Is it possible to do envelope distortion a picture or a path using JavaScript and HTML5. Is there any libraries available or can you point me in the right direction.

Here is and example using flash and actionscript.
http://www.neuroproductions.be/experiments/envelope-distort-with-actionscript/

http://www.neuroproductions.be/uploads/blog/examples/envelope_distort/EnvelopeDistordTest.swf

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to provide more context and show us what effort you have made in solving your problem before anyone can answer this question with a more complex answer than "Yes, it's possible." Try it for yourself, and let us know where you are having difficulties. If you don't know where to start, I would recommend a Google search.

Comment: I think a straight port (to ES5/canvas) of the code you linked would work. Have you tried that? I might try it later just for fun.

Comment: Sorry Paul, I am new to html5, I have done a lot of Google search before I posted here. I couldn't fine any good resources on getting it done.

Comment: GGG I will try a straight port, the only thing is that the code uses some internal flash classes. Do you have any good port resources for action-script users.  Thanks

Comment: I have ported the above example to Javascript as shown in my blog post -http://inkxe.com/blog/text-within-a-shape-test-demo/

Comment: @susrut316 Nice! Have you posted the script somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: No @ALx but I have ported the exact code to Javascript.

Comment: @susrut316 the original code seems to be gone. Care to share your port? Thank you.